# Is it possible to use a switch statement with an enum to catch unset flags

Tags: c#, enums

Is it possible to use an switch statement to catch unset flags in an enum? I have tried appending a ! to the front of the `sampleEnum.Unset1` etc but that has not worked.

```
public enum sampleEnum
{
    Set1   = 1,
    Set2   = 2,
    Unset4 = 4,
    Set8   = 8
}

switch (sampleEnum)
{
    case sampleEnum.Set1:
        Console.WriteLine("This should not run");
        break;
    case sampleEnum.Set2:
        Console.WriteLine("This should not run");
        break;
    case sampleEnum.Unset4:
        Console.WriteLine("This should run");
        break;
    case sampleEnum.Set8:
        Console.WriteLine("This should not run");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#pattern) about available types of comparison with `switch`. If you need other types of comparison, use an `if` statement.

Comment: If you are trying to trap for a specific enum value ("unset") why would you have code for all the other OK values?

Comment: Because it's an example... if I knew it would only ever be the same input why would I bother writing a switch statement at all? In reality any of them could be false but I only want to run the first one found to be false.

Comment: There is no such thing as an un-set enum value. If you don't specify a value for an item, it gets the previous item's value +1. But I may not be understanding the question here, since you have values set for all of them.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you defined what an "unset flag" is, or provided a more real-world example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: If the HasFlag function returned false then that is what I mean by an unset flag. Apologies I have missed the [flags] bit from the top of the enum.

Comment: It is the kind of enum declaration that ought to have the [Flags] attribute.  Any combination of bits in the enum variable value ought to be valid, like sampleEnum.Set1 | sampleEnum.Set2.  You can't test that with a switch, it requires multiple if-statements.  What "unset" is supposed to mean is murky, perhaps you are looking for if ((value & sampleEnum.Unset4) == sampleEnum.Unset4) die();

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what real scenario you are concerned about, but we should be able to work through this

I changed some names, but assuming an Enum :

```
public enum enumExampo
{
    Set1   = 1,
    Set2   = 2,
    Unset4 = 4,
    Set8   = 8,
    set9 = 9
}
```

I setup a method like:

```
public static void checkExampo(enumExampo exampo)
{
    switch (exampo)
    {
        case enumExampo.Set1:
            Console.WriteLine("This should not run");
            break;
        case enumExampo.Set2:
            Console.WriteLine("This should not run");
            break;
        case enumExampo.Unset4:
            Console.WriteLine("This should run");
            break;
        case enumExampo.Set8:
            Console.WriteLine("This should not run");
            break;
        case new enumExampo():
            Console.WriteLine("is a new Instance");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine($"Default, flagged for {exampo}");
            break;
    }
}
```

And then the usage:

```
 var sampleEnum = new enumExampo();
 var exNiner = enumExampo.set9;

 checkExampo(sampleEnum);
 checkExampo(exNiner);
```

gives us the results in the console of:

> is a new Instance 
>   Default, flagged for set9

Answer (score 0):

The `switch` statement can only handle the equality comparison against a constant. So it is very limited. The only way to do what you ask would be something silly like this:

```
switch (sampleEnum)
{
    case sampleEnum.Set4:
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("This only runs when Set4 is not set.");
        break;
}
```

If the comparison is at all complicated, it is probably best to use `if`, which is much more flexible (and in my opinion easier to read anyway).

```
if (!sampleEnum.HasFlag(Set4))
{
    Console.WriteLine("This will run only when Set4 is not set.");
}
```